# How can I get Visual Studio to refuse to compile if there are Typescript errors?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

When I try to compile a Typescript file with errors, I expect Visual Studio to simply halt the compilation and show me the errors, like it does with every other language.

Instead, it blindly goes ahead and runs the app. This happens even though I've ticked off "Do not emit outputs if any errors are reported".

I've noticed if I turn off "Compile on save," then I get this behavior. But then I'm giving up faster compilations! Is there any way to get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the **noEmitOnError** in the project`s **tsconfig.json** file should result in this behaviour.